# WebAudio API data array size?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

So, I'm displaying the waveform and FFT of the sound stream coming from the microphone using the WebAudio API.

My question is, how large is each data array available at a specific moment? For example, look at the [getByteTimeDomainData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteTimeDomainData) function from the `AnalyserNode`. It says in the docs that it `"copies the current waveform, or time-domain, data into a Uint8Array"`. What exactly is the `current waveform` ? Last second of sound input? Does the size of the current waveform data depend on the input frequency?

In other wards, being more like a stream interface that receives chunks of data, how large is each chunk? If we only get the time domain data once every 100ms do we miss the sound that happened between those times or is the sound wave buffered until the next `getByteTimeDomainData` call?

Answer (score 2):

You set the size, with the fftSize attribute on AnalyserNode.  Yes, you will "miss the sound that happened between those times" - if you need to do something like that, use ScriptProcessor.

Comment: So, if I set fftSize to `2048` the frequencyBinCount will be`1024`, so every time I call `getByteTimeDomainData` I will get `1024` values. If the input frequency is 48000hz does this mean I only get the last 1024/48000 = `0.00213` seconds ~= 2 milliseconds?

Comment: Yes.  Although "last" is kind of inaccurate - it's not keeping a continuously-feeding stream of samples, the audio processing system tends to push things through in blocks; particularly on high-latency systems (like Linux).  But it is a "recent" block of ~2ms in your example, yes.